# Add Drift and Hubspot(third party JS) to AMP pages

Tags: wordpress, amp-html, hubspot, drift

is there an official way or case study of how to add external marketing tools, like trackers(hubspot), bots(drift), etc, to basic AMP pages generated in a WordPress setups using the official AMP plugin? The idea of AMP is to filter JS, but for marketing, using external tracking tools is a must, and the AMP performance is great for SEO, any idea of how to combine both worlds?

Answer (score 0):

We have been using pure amp sites for years now, the problem you face is what we have faced over and over again. Unless these tools will integrate to use the `<amp-analytics>` module, you will not be able to use tools like this. `<amp-analytics>`, however, gives you all the data you need, you can record visits, clicks, conversions etc and with a bit of tweaking, you could even pass this data to HubSpot via their API.

Please visit the documentation for here: [`<amp-analytics>`](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-analytics/?format=websites)

In regards to live chat (Drift), you would have to build a live chat via amp and use this instead of drift. Google AMP will not allow 3rd party javascript.